# How to save Javascript variable between frames?

Tags: javascript, html, variables, frame, parent-child

I have a javascript variable called "myvar" in two different frames (frame1 and frame2). I need to take the myvar in frame1 and set it as the value of the myvar in frame2. How do I do this without an external script?

Comment: no, I'm just using framesets.

Comment: Save it to `window.parent`?

Comment: That having been said, you should probably be asking "why am I using framesets?"... It's 2013 man.

Comment: Working with cruddy computers that aren't exactly in the 21st century.

Comment: What do old PCs have to do with the use of old web technologies? Isn't that the whole reason? Harness the power of the server?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If the variable is in the parent, use:

```
window.parent.varName
```

If it's in another frame, go through the parent, then to the frame:

```
window.parent.frameName.varName
```

Comment: How do you change the varName? could you use an example using "myvar" as both variables?

Comment: window.parent.frame1.myvar = window.parent.frame2.myvar

Comment: This only works for same scheme domains:port. As of same domain policy. Just to be curious.

Comment: are both frames on the same domain? sub domains on the same TLD?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I needed to pass two variables. I only passed one. It's working now. Thanks.